# MethodnotallowedExeption when I patch from previous post route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-validation

First of all its not the entry level error that I am sending a request to a wrong route verb.

My case its this: I have a post route

```
Route::post('/user/edit', 'UserController@edit');
```

when I hit this route I have a random form to update a specific user details. The thing is when I submit the form it goes to route:

```
Route::put('user/update','UserController@update');
```

All working. But I want to add a lil bit of validation so user does not send me the same existing data so I added a validation for that :

```
  if($this->method() =='PUT'){
        return [
            'name'=>'required|unique:users,name'
        ];
    }
```

The thing is when validation kicks in it redirects back with the messages I can catch the session manually and I see that validation is working, and it should send back to first route but I get a method not allowed exception. I assume validation base method sends a GET request back ?

Any idea how to come over this issue >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is how validation works. When data is invalid there is made redirection to form using obviously GET method.

In general you shouldn't display forms in POST action. Usually what you should do is redirecting to some other route that is available via GET. This is done usually also for multi-step forms:

**GET step1 -> POST step 1 -> GET step 2 -> POST step 2 and so on.**

So you should do exactly the same in your case to make it work with validation.

Comment: okay I will do then, but in my edit form I do have select html tag with value attribute containing ```user_id```  question how do I bind ```user_id``` to a laravel route ?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because validator sends a response with HTTP status code 302, and redirects are always interpreted as `GET` by the browser itself.

You should never use other method then `GET` when you are showing a page to the user to avoid this kind of problems. Create a `GET` route to show your form, if necessary to show a form after a `POST` request, use a redirect to you `GET` route.

Comment: heads up I already know that validator has a GET callback, and the thing is that I want its my desire to user POST request in this case. It seems Laravel framework leaks there.

Comment: Laravel isn't wrong, you expected behavior is not usual. You always can extend the validator. <strike>Wait a while, I'll update the answer if a how to.</strike>

Comment: Actually, you can NOT do this. As I've explained, you cant send a HTTP redirect and choice the method to browser use. You can use redirect status code 307 to tell to browser to redirect using the same method and content data, BUT this isn't what you need, since your request that triggers the redirect is PUT and you want to redirect to POST.

Please see this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

Comment: the thing is that I do not wanna override any base class, since I though it might be a simple solution out there. Well if you could tell me how to bind a wildcard to a laravel route from a select html tag. In that case I would change my POST route to GET.